# dplyr and checking previous 24-60 months for observations

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a bunch of unique cusip codes(unique ID) and need to check to make sure there are 24-60 previous month observations, but am not sure how to check this with `dplyr`

### Reproducible example :

```
tdata <- structure(list(cusip = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), fyear = c("1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", 
"1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", 
"1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", 
"1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", "1973", "1973", "1973", 
"1973", "1973", "1973", "1973", "1973", "1973", "1973", "1973", 
"1973", "1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", 
"1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", "1975", "1975", "1975", 
"1975", "1975", "1975", "1975", "1975", "1975", "1975", "1975"
), datadate = c(19711231L, 19710129L, 19710226L, 19710331L, 19710430L, 
19710528L, 19710630L, 19710730L, 19710831L, 19710930L, 19711029L, 
19711130L, 19721231L, 19720131L, 19720229L, 19720330L, 19720428L, 
19720531L, 19720630L, 19720731L, 19720831L, 19720929L, 19721031L, 
19721130L, 19721229L, 19731231L, 19730131L, 19730228L, 19730330L, 
19730430L, 19730531L, 19730629L, 19730731L, 19730831L, 19730928L, 
19731031L, 19731130L, 19741231L, 19740131L, 19740228L, 19740329L, 
19740430L, 19740531L, 19740628L, 19740731L, 19740830L, 19740930L, 
19741031L, 19741129L, 19751231L, 19750131L, 19750228L, 19750331L, 
19750430L, 19750530L, 19750630L, 19750731L, 19750829L, 19750930L, 
19751031L)), .Names = c("cusip", "fyear", "datadate"), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -60L), vars = list(
    cusip, fyear), drop = TRUE, indices = list(0:11, 12:24, 25:36, 
    37:48, 49:59), group_sizes = c(12L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 11L), biggest_group_size = 13L, labels = structure(list(
    cusip = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2), fyear = c("1971", "1972", "1973", 
    "1974", "1975")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), .Names = c("cusip", "fyear"), vars = list(cusip, fyear)))
```

### Logic

I was thinking about checking the total months for each year, but don't know know to extract the previous to months to check if 24/60 >= 0.4.  How would I edited this code to check the previous 60 months and ensure there are at least 24 months including....

```
tdata %>% 
  group_by(cusip, fyear) %>% 
  mutate(month = substr(datadate, 5, 6) %>% 
  mutate(pre_countmonths = length(unique(month))
```

### Edit 04/07/2015 :

Here is the logic I am following with for loops.  One of the challenges I'm having with R is branching outside of for loops.  Any possible way to edit this where `dplyr` can be utilized instead of `for` loops?  This will take entirely too long to run with my current data.

```
for(i in min(tdata$cusip):max(tdata$cusip)){ 
    for (j in min(tdata$fyear):max(tdata$fyear) {
      monthcheck <- filter(tdata, cusip == i & (fyear == j-1 | fyear == j-2 | fyear == j-3 | fyear == j-4))
      if(length(monthcheck$month) / 40 >= 0.4) if(any(tdata$fyear == j)) tdata$check <- 1 
}}
```

### Edit : 04/08/2015 - Added full sample dataset with main variables

Small Subset : https://www.dropbox.com/s/mf0o0tbgbame6k8/testdata.csv?dl=0

Comment: You want to know if there are more than 24 previous data points counting from the last observation for each cusip. Is that right?

Comment: @jazzurro for each cusip and year...this data set starts with July, so it should reflect the previous two years starting with June....

Comment: Does that mean you want to know whether there are more than 24 data points counting back from 1975-07-31 in this example?

Comment: Yes, but it needs to be months, not observations, because an individual firm may not have reported every month and those should be deleted because I need consecutive reports for 24-60 months

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I got within my time limit. I hope that this gives you some ideas, and that other users provide better solutions.

```
mydf <- as_data_frame(list(cusip = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), fyear = c("1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", 
"1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", "1971", 
"1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", 
"1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", "1972", "1973", "1973", "1973", 
"1973", "1973", "1973", "1973", "1973", "1973", "1973", "1973", 
"1973", "1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", 
"1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", "1974", "1975", "1975", "1975", 
"1975", "1975", "1975", "1975", "1975", "1975", "1975", "1975"
), datadate = c(19711231L, 19710129L, 19710226L, 19710331L, 19710430L, 
19710528L, 19710630L, 19710730L, 19710831L, 19710930L, 19711029L, 
19711130L, 19721231L, 19720131L, 19720229L, 19720330L, 19720428L, 
19720531L, 19720630L, 19720731L, 19720831L, 19720929L, 19721031L, 
19721130L, 19721229L, 19731231L, 19730131L, 19730228L, 19730330L, 
19730430L, 19730531L, 19730629L, 19730731L, 19730831L, 19730928L, 
19731031L, 19731130L, 19741231L, 19740131L, 19740228L, 19740329L, 
19740430L, 19740531L, 19740628L, 19740731L, 19740830L, 19740930L, 
19741031L, 19741129L, 19751231L, 19750131L, 19750228L, 19750331L, 
19750430L, 19750530L, 19750630L, 19750731L, 19750829L, 19750930L, 
19751031L)))

# Make it normal data.frame
mydf <- data.frame(mydf)

# Create another data frame with a new cusip
mydf2 <- mutate(mydf, cusip = 3)

### Create a new data frame which is missing one data point
foo <- bind_rows(mydf, mydf2[-4, ])
```

In this pseudo data, cusip 3 is missing one month data. That means, you do not have consecutive 24-60-month data for `cusip` 3. First, I created a column with month and a column with date object. Then, I ordered your data by `cusp` and datadate. I wanted to select data points which stay between this 24-60 month period. This is the first `filter` part. I grouped the data by `cusp`. Using month, I wanted to check if I have consecutive data points or not. You would expect `lead(month)-month` = 1, 11, or 0. If you have two data points from a same month, you would expect 0. That is happening in your data. The final `filter` is something you can revise. Here, I wanted to remove any `cusip` which got FALSE in check. In this draft, this filter seems to be doing the right thing; you do not see any data of cusip 3 in the end. I hope this helps you.

```
mutate(foo, month = as.numeric(substr(datadate, 5, 6))) %>%
mutate(datadate = as.POSIXct(gsub("^(\\d{4})(\\d{2}).*$", "\\1-\\2-01", datadate),
                  format("%Y-%m-%d"), tz = "GMT")) %>%  
arrange(cusip, datadate) %>%                        
filter(between(datadate, 
       datadate[tail(which(month == 6, arr.ind = TRUE), n = 1)] - (60*60*24*30*60),
       datadate[tail(which(month == 6, arr.ind = TRUE), n = 1)] -(60*60*24*30*24))) %>%
group_by(cusip) %>%
mutate(check = abs(lead(month)-month) == 11|abs(lead(month)-month) == 1|abs(lead(month)-month) == 0) %>%
filter(all(check == TRUE | check %in% NA))
```

Comment: After appl ying this to the larger dataset, it seems like the first `filter` command is not working correctly.  I've stepped through it and this returns 0 obs....any idea why?  I'm not following the logic in this step

Comment: @Amstell there are several data points with June in your data. I wanted to pick up the last. I have done it with `datadate[tail(which(month == 6, arr.ind = TRUE), n = 1)]`. Using this data point, I wanted to pick up data points which stays between previous 24 and 60 months. `(60*60*24*30*60)` is the equivalent of 6 months, for example. In short, the filter is filtering data for the 24-60-month period. I am not sure why the filter did not work with your data; it is working on my machine. I wonder if there are any differences between my sample data here and your real data.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation...The sample code you created worked fine, but won't with the full data set.  I've added it to the question with only the 3 variables needed.  I checked it with this and it's still returning 0.  Any idea what is going on?

Comment: @Amstell I downloaded your file and tested the code above. I have 179866 obs in the end. So, the code seems to be working with the new sample data. I am not sure why you receive nothing after the first filter.

Comment: You're right it did work.  I was running into problems with grouping with `dplyr` so I ungrouped the data frame and ran it....works get....thanks....could you explain the `(60*60*24*30*60)` being 6 months?  I don't understand this

Comment: @Amstell Glad to hear that the code worked for you. 60*60*24 = 86400 seconds. That is a day. You have that 30 times in a month (30 days). You may want to revise this part. Anyway, the last 60 is 60 months. so `(60*60*24*30*60)` is 6 months in seconds.

Comment: I see about the seconds....but I don't see where the seconds are being compared in datadate...and why transform the original datadate?

Comment: I gotta get ready to go to work now. Quickly, `datadate` is a date object in the 2nd `mutate`. The original `datadate` is not a date object. If you want to search data points with stays in your 24-60-month period, I think you need date objects. Once you know which June you target for each cusip, you want to know which year/month stay in the period, right? The first filter is asking R to pick up data points which stay in the period for each cusip.  (60*60*24*30*60) and  (60*60*24*30*24) are added to the June you identified for each cusip.

Comment: `datadate[tail(which(month == 6, arr.ind = TRUE), n = 1)]` is an actual date. You are subtracting 24 months & 60 months from the date. In this way, I created the 24-60 month period.

Comment: Ok thank you so much for the answer and follow up help...the dataset is a bit funny in that a year is defined from July - June....so for each previous 24-60 months prior July should exist...is this still working for this?

Comment: I gotta go now. If you want to include July, `datadate[tail(which(month == 7, arr.ind = TRUE), n = 1)] ` would be the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your help....for this to work correctly, it needs to be set to 6....thanks again for yoru help.